# Setup node.js App for pubblication with PM2

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, pm2

I have a node.js application that uses the python-shell module. When I start the app with the command: *node server.js* everything works well, including Python scripts. If I try to start the application with the *pm2 start logs server* command, Python scripts do not work and I get a lot of errors on PythonShell, Object.callPythonScript.

Does anyone know how to fix and how does the application normally work with the node compiler, but not with pm2?

This is the logs error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably you should attach some screenshots of the errors you get.

Comment: I have attached it, I hope it helps to understand something more.